# Why display: flex hide my image in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

For some reason two images won't display even tho using the same path some images are displaying.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    minHeight: "100vh",
    fontFamily: fonts.extra,
    fontWeight: "100",
  },
  heading: {
    height: "55vh",
    backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/ichud-bg.jpg"})`,
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
  },
  headingText: {
    fontSize: "64px",
    padding: "20px",
    border: "5px solid #000",
    color: colors.black,

    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)",
  },
  imageWrapper: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  firstImage: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/ichud-bg.jpg"})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    height: "500px",
  },
  secondImage: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/cards2.jpg"})`,
    height: "500px",
    width: "400px",
  },
}));
```

This is the style.

```js
export default function Ichud() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.heading}>
        <h1 className={classes.headingText}>ICHUD MOSDOS</h1>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.imageWrapper}>
        <div className={classes.firstImage}></div>
        <div className={classes.secondImage}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The image on heading is displaying but the "firstImage" and "secondImage" are not.

Every type of help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually I guess the display attribute is the problem. If i set flexDirection to row and i don't assing the display: flex i can see them in a column.

Comment: Also i tried to add an another component under the divs and it’s not displaying as well.

Comment: PS: Actually this problem is persistent in my project omg I'm feeling so lost atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing your code the `heading` image and `secondImage` show up. The reason `firstImage` doesn't show up is because it has no `width`.

So instead of this:

```
firstImage: {
  backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/ichud-bg.jpg"})`,
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  height: "500px"
}
```

Make it something like this:

```
firstImage: {
  backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/ichud-bg.jpg"})`,
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  height: "500px",
  width: "400px"
}
```

If you're also not seeing `secondImage` then that `cards2` path must be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd upvote it but need 4 more reputation, lol. For sure I will comeback here then.

Comment: Glad to help. You can also accept answers by the way to show that an answer solved your problem in addition to upvoting posts you find helpful. To accept an answer you can press the checkmark. Accepting an answer has no reputation requirement, but you can only accept one answer.